# Dynamically change pie series color Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a very simple pie chart with highcharts.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        renderTo: 'container'                    
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'TnE Completion',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: "30px"
                        }
                    },
                    navigation: {
                        buttonOptions: {
                            enabled:false
                        }
                    },                  
                    data: {
                            googleSpreadsheetKey: '10t39JsAyon73X3ss84n7bUkHBil67DKwpIHH9eCj1PQ'
                    }
                };

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);              
        });
```

What I would like to do is to change the color of the slices. I have Googled this and looked on this forum but cannot find a way to do this without parsing the data first.

Any assistance Would be greatly appreciated.

Tone

Comment: Your google spreadsheet is not accessible - data cannot be loaded. Generally you can use [data.parsed](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.parsed) or [data.complete](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.complete) to modify data. Other way would be to use chart's callback or [load event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) for changing data before first rendering of a chart.